# Can't install activity log Laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel-5.7

I try to install composer require spatie/laravel-activitylog but I got failed there is anyway to fix this problem?

```
Problem 1
- Installation request for spatie/laravel-activitylog ^3.5 -> satisfiable by spatie/laravel-activitylog[3.5.0].
- Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.7.28
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
- spatie/laravel-activitylog 3.5.0 requires illuminate/config ~5.8.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[5.8.x-dev], illuminate/config[5.8.x-dev, v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.2, v5.8.3, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9].
- Can only install one of: laravel/framework[5.8.x-dev, v5.7.28].
- don't install illuminate/config 5.8.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
- don't install illuminate/config v5.8.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
- don't install illuminate/config v5.8.11|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
- don't install illuminate/config v5.8.12|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
- don't install illuminate/config v5.8.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
- don't install illuminate/config v5.8.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
- don't install illuminate/config v5.8.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
- don't install illuminate/config v5.8.8|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
- don't install illuminate/config v5.8.9|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
- Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v5.7.28, required as 5.7.*) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.7.28].
```

Thank Q

(Solved) by composer require spatie/laravel-activitylog 3.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

v3.3.0 has dropped the support for L5.7 & PHP7.1

https://github.com/spatie/laravel-activitylog/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#330---2019-04-08

So you have to run below command

> composer require spatie/laravel-activitylog:^3.2

Answer (score 0):

You can check official docs for requirements: https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-activitylog/v3/requirements/ , currently latest version requires laravel 6.0 or higher, if you have an older version of the framework you need to install an older version of activity logger, like @Chirag Shan suggested.